# installed ubuntu 13.04 but no wireless or wired connection available

Tags: wireless, wired

after having installed ubuntu 13.04 i can not connect to the internet wirelessly or wired? can only connect to internet by using "try ubuntu" via ethernet cable, ive tried seeking help in so many different ways yet getting no positive outcome at all, will someone please explain why i can only connect with ethernet while i have the cd in the tray? ive also tried downloading b43 drivers to connect to the internet but apparently i dont have enough disk space, what is going on here?

i have the disk in the tray now at the screen where you can either try or install, if someone could give me a step by step from here it would probably cut out all this hassle of me not knowing whats going on

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I was digging around trying to find a place you could download the drivers and then install them but here's what I found

[WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access)

And

[Package: bcmwl-kernel-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/bcmwl-kernel-source)

Hope this helps.

Comment: im just in the proceeds of downloading additional drivers from the ubuntu software, if it fails ill try your advice, thanks! its just that i cant get connection without using the cd, after i install and run without cd there is no connection available thus making it impossible to download any drivers

Comment: That's why I was trying to find a way to download them, stick it on a jump drive, then attempt install them after the install.

Comment: the only thing i have is a 1 terabyte external hard drive, should i download the drivers on that, and copy them into ubuntu? only problem there would be that i wouldnt know where to copy them haha, im hopeless :)

Answer (score 0):

There have been some issues with the network drives in ubuntu (and kubuntu). I've found that I have to use `echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control` to get the cabled ethernet to come up.

If that works, you should then be able to download the drives you need for the wifi card.

Bug report is here [ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1112652)